# How in Log4j2 properties file define arbiters or conditional logic?

Tags: log4j, log4j2, properties-file

So, while using log4j2 we can set in xml, yaml files arbiters, that will take env variable and run appropriate part of config based on that.

I'm using .properties file and I can't find anything in the apache documentation nor by trying manually create arbiters, to conditionally run loggers based on env variable.
The only option I've found is using separate files and loading them based on your config, but I would prefer to have an option like there is for xml and yaml.

It doesn't have to be arbiter, but I want to know how to conditionally add config in .properties log4j2 files.